# Category/Product Pageviews Magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I run an ecommerce company which is made on Magento.
I need to find Category and Product wise page views and conversions for my website.
Google Analytics does not show me the Pageviews data for the said groups.
Is there a way to track the same in GA or some extension to do so.
We tried to use Jirafe, the data was right but it seems to run the cron every hour and would 
at times use too many DB instances and thus eating into site bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

I've got a template that included a popular products widget for the homepage. While researching how to remove a product I *didn't* want in there, I stumbled up the table `report_viewed_product_index` which may or nay not be part of their template's code.

The people are "Templates Master" and the module which contains this code is "TM Highlight". The below query may not be perfectly exact, but at least corresponds to our "top 5" products widget.

```sql
<?
SELECT sfoi.sku, count(rvpi.product_id) 
FROM 
report_viewed_product_index rvpi
INNER JOIN
( SELECT DISTINCT sku, product_id FROM sales_flat_order_item ) as sfoi
ON sfoi.product_id=rvpi.product_id 
GROUP BY rvpi.product_id 
ORDER BY count(rvpi.product_id) DESC  
LIMIT 0,10;

+------------+------------------------+
| sku        | count(rvpi.product_id) |
+------------+------------------------+
| HM69.BLK   |                  11055 | 
| FP-HUS     |                   3455 | 
| 2VCOILS    |                   2829 | 
| TB900      |                   1920 | 
| 460-1505   |                   1396 | 
| 2112-0061  |                   1293 | 
| JAMBNUTS   |                   1077 | 
| VM520-110  |                   1076 | 
| TR200038PC |                   1066 | 
| 016-721    |                   1008 | 
+------------+------------------------+
?>
```